# Имена библиотек gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

Из литературы по С++ известны наименования библиотек (например, math). В линуксовском компиляторе gcc (а возможно и в g++) эта библиотека называется libm. Исходя из этого, параметром терминальной команды (создающей запускаемый файл) нужно указать –lm (получается из libm заменой lib на l). Вопрос: из чего следует, что библиотека math в gcc именуется libm?

Answer (score 2):

1. Из исходных кодов
2. Из документаций
3. Из простейшей логики: *libm* = **lib**rary **m**ath

Если ее писал не ты, то не нужно искать причин почему библиотека названа так, как она названа.

Answer (score 2):

Параметры командной строки `-l` заставляют компилятор искать библиотеку с заданным именем. То, что идёт после буквы `l` является именем (первый пробел игнорируется). Поиск производится следующий образом:

1. Рассматривается каждый из каталогов поиска библиотек по порядку. Дополнительные каталоги можно указать параметром `-L` аналогично имени библиотеки. По умолчанию этот список содержит такие каталоги:

   - `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5` (может быть иная архитектура или версия GCC)
   - `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (архитектура может отличаться)
   - `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`  (архитектура может отличаться)
   - `/lib`
   - `/usr/lib`
2. Если хотя бы в одном из каталогов поиска будет найден файл с именем `libбиблиотека.so` или `libбиблиотека.a`, поиск останавливается и выбирается файл, содержащий определения нужных функций (и иных символов).
3. Если в каталоге несколько файлов подходят под шаблоны выше, то без указания опции `--static`, выбор происходит по вышеуказанному порядку. Если заказана статическая компоновка, приоритеты меняются наоборот. По умолчанию выполняется динамическая компоновка, т.е. предполагается параметр `--shared`.

*Примечание:* названия библиотек рекомендуется перечислять после всех исходных файлов.

Что делать, если имя файла с библиотекой не начинается с букв `lib`? Просто укажите к нему путь относительно текущего каталога.

### Примеры:

Компиляция программы, использующей стандартную математическую библиотеку.

```
gcc my_prog.c -lm
```

Или что то же самое

```
gcc my_prog.c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so  # путь может отличаться
```

Впрочем, на некоторых системах можно обойтись без явного указания библиотеки **m**.

Компиляция программы, написанной на фреймворке Qt, причём сама Qt установлена владельцем системы вручную

```
gcc my_prog.c -L/usr/local/lib/qt5 -lQt5Core
```

---

В качестве эксперимента, посмотрите, какие библиотеки вам доступны командой

```
ls /usr/lib/*.so /usr/lib/*/*.so
```

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан, спасибо